# Extending CCSprite

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

Imagine a whirligig which causes a palette of textures to scroll from one side of the screen to the other. We will randomly choose the texture within a given rectangle to mimic the functionality of a carousel of images.

```
        //Header file of the Texture Embedded. This is Fabric.h

         class Fabric: public WhirligigNetwork {
         .....
         ........
          void initFabric(void);

          public: 

         static Fabric * create();
```

I statically initialize the main object:

```
     //In Fabric.cpp

     //Fabric create function.

    Fabric * Fabric::create() {

   Fabric * fabric = new Fabric();
    if (fabric && fabric-> initWithSpriteFrameName("fabric.png")) {
    fabric->autorelease();
    fabric->initObstacle();
    return fabric;
      }
     CC_SAFE_DELETE(fabric);
     return NULL;

       }
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to extend 'Fabric' (which is a mask over the class CCSprite) and compile, Xcode has a hard time figuring out what Fabric really is. :confused

```
  /*So let's say that we're implementing a randomized selection of fabric elements that are           
      assigned to a whirligig of Sprite 'containers'.*/

class WhirligigNetwork : public Sprite {

                  .................
           .......................
       //Xcode does not know type name (Fabric) - the override is useless.

           //An Array of Fabrics!
          cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Sprite *> _fabrics;

            void initFabric(Fabric * fabrics); /* doesn't run */

      /* If I play around with inline helper methods to query for a countable set of widths*/

         inline float getWideness() {

         //then I order and count the elements of my Vector<T>
         int count = _fabrics.size();

           //Default
             int wideness = 0;

    //Deal with the heap.
    class Fabric * fabrics;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fabric = (class Fabric *) _fabics.at(i);

        // set-increment wideness
        wideness += fabric->getWideness();
    }
    return wideness;
}
```

Member access into incomplete type 'class Fabric'...any suggestions?

Comment: So you are trying to use an inheriting class in the inherited class? That's some circular dependency there. You might want to look into the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: static polymorphism sounds about right.

Comment: Also note that in C++ class and structure names can be used directly as types, no use for the `class` in e.g. `class Fabric * fabrics;`, `Fabric * fabrics;` will work just as well.

Comment: well, for some reason, without the class it doesn't run..thanks for asking, I struggled with that.

Comment: Regarding unneeded keywords, when you define a member function inside a class definition, like you have with `WhirligigNetwork::getWideness` you don't need the `inline` keyword, the compiler will treat it as `inline` anyway. Also note that `inline` is actually just a *hint* to the compiler that it *may* inline the function if it wants to, it's not an order that it must do it.

Comment: You said "extending CCSprite" but your base class of WhirligigNetwork is "Sprite". Shouldn't it be CCSprite here? And maybe you should instead subclass CCNode if you intend to do your own custom drawing and not perusing any of the CCSprite drawing functionality.

Comment: FYI, There is this too: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_To_Subclass_Sprite_And_Add_Event_Listeners

Comment: @LearnCocos2D because Node is a "void" object drawing is discouraged.

Comment: who says so? In fact ccnode is the template class to use for custom drawing specifically because it doesn't come with any properties and methods for built-in drawing that might conflict with custom drawing or merely bloat the custom drawing class with unused variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *circular dependency*.

You need to define the class `Fabric` before you define `WhirligigNetwork`, but you can't do that because `Fabric` needs `WhirligigNetwork` to be defined first.

The simple solution is to *declare* the class `Fabric` before the `WhirligigNetwork` definition, and then put the member function implementation in a separate source file where you can safely include both header files in the correct order.

So in the header file for `WhirligigNetwork` you have e.g.

```
#ifndef WHIRLIGIGNETWORK_H
#define WHIRLIGIGNETWORK_H

// Declare the class Fabric
class Fabric;

// Define the class WhirligigNetwork
class WhirligigNetwork : public Sprite
{
private:
    cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Sprite *> _fabrics;

    ...

public:
    ...

    float getWideness();

    ...
};

#endif
```

And in the source file for `WhirligigNetwork`:

```
#include "whirligignetwork.h"
#include "fabric.h"

// Can use `Fabric` freely in here

...

float WhirligigNetwork::getWideness()
{
    ...
}
```